# Accessing parent scope value with standard method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Today I wondered after some strange behavior of angularjs. I used console.log to log $scope, there were no key attached to scope named val1, but when I use `console.log($scope.val1)` its returning value as a object. After digging out the reason, I found that it was accessing parent scope as there is no kay named val1 in $scope. Now my question is that,

> Which is good practice? Can you please justify?

1. Using `$scope.$parent.val1`
2. Using `$scope.val1`

Comment: Provide a simple example demo. Would be better to answer this within the context of real code. Short answer is everything starts at `$rootScope` and all scopes are in a tree within `$rootScope`

Comment: The good practice is not to use scopes inheritance. It's may be the cause of the misunderstandings. If you need to share some value between the controllers, you better use `services`.

Comment: @valverde93 that's an overly broad statement. What about `ng-repeat` where you automatically are using inheritance because a child scope is created for each repeat?

Comment: @valverde93, if you use any custom directive inside element which has ng-controller, then there will be two scopes for that directive elements, one is of directive, and another is of controllers which is parent scope for that directive.

Comment: @charlietfl You're right. `ng-repeat` creates its own scope. But it's a native Angular behavior that has the great documentation and description. And if you want to realize similar behavior, that mean that you have to write the description to your code. It's like a clean code agreement.

Comment: @LaxmikantDange best answer to your exact question would be ... forget that `$parent` property even exists when you are writing code. Don't however forget that non isolated child scopes do inherit from parent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should generally never use `$scope.$parent` and instead rely on Javascripts prototypal inheritance. By accessing the parent directly, you run the risk of the code breaking if you move the directive/controller a step up in the scope hierarchy, and the data is now on `$scope.$parent.$parent` instead.

Instead, never write to properties directly on the scope but to objects on the scope object instead.

Say you do:

```
$scope.$parent.value = 'x';
```

Then you do:

```
console.log($scope.value);
```

That'll print `x` to the console. If you then do:

```
$scope.value = 'y';
```

You're not modifying the `value` property on the parent scope, but introducing a new property on the child scope. So `$scope.$parent.value` will still contain `x`.

To get around that, you do:

```
$scope.$parent.data = {value: 'x'};
console.log($scope.data.value); // prints x
$scope.data.value = 'y';
console.log($scope.data.value); // prints y
console.log($scope.$parent.data.value); // also prints y
```

The reason this works is that instead of creating a new `value` property on the child scope, it first needs to lookup the `data` property. And that's not on the child scope, so it goes up the prototype chain ($parent) to find the `data` object. The `data` object is found on the parent, and the `value` property is set on that object instead.

Comment: But which is good practice? by accessing directly that property using chain of $parent or directly using $scope.val1?

Comment: @LaxmikantDange read first sentence in answer....should never use `$parent` in your code, otherwise you aren't doing something right and there is almost always a way to set things up to not need to do it

Comment: Me using `$scope.$parent` in the answer was just an example to get my point across. You should never access `$parent` unless you have a *very* good reason.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of `val1`, in case it is a primitive, you will have to access it explicitly via $scope.$parent.
In case it is an object, you can take advantage of the prototypal inheritance that exists between parent and child scope in Angular and just reference it regularly, as I am sure you are aware of, objects are passed by reference, so any change to the object will change it on the parent scope.

[More info here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)